# How do I create a shared folder/remotely control a printer between two Ubuntu machines?

Tags: wireless, printing, sharing

I have an upstairs and downstairs computer; I'd love to know how to create a shared folder between the two (through a wireless network)

I'd also love to know if there is any way to get my upstairs computer to send a file to my downstairs computer (which has the printer) and get it to print, through a wireless network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both :)

I have now successfully got the printer and a shared folder on the network. :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume that both computers are running Linux. Then you can configure cups on your downstairs computer to publish the connected printer. The cups daemon on you upstairs computer then automatically sees the published printer and you can select it from the usual printer dialog.

You can configure cups via the web-interace, i.e. you can connect to http://127.0.0.1:631 (on the computer with the printer.

The automatically discovering of the shared printer on the printer-less computer only works, if both computers are on the same subnet and if the computer has the show-broadcasted-printers-option in cups enabled. Don't remember what is the current default under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can share a printer on one computer by right-clicking on it. On the other computer you add a network printer using the ipp protocol.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers has more details.